# Widgets de ventana hija creada con Toplevel se muestran en la ventana principal

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

Necesito ayuda con Tkinter de Python 2.7 ya que estoy desarrollando una pequeña interfaz gráfica para gestionar una base de datos en mysql.

Lo que quiero es que al presionar un botón, este abra una ventana nueva `Toplevel` que ya contenga labels y Entrys. Lo intenté con el código que dejo a continuación pero cuando le doy al botón abre bien la ventana pero el `Entry` y el `Label` los deja en la ventana principal y no en la nueva ventana. ¿Qué esta mal?

```
def win2 ():
  t1 = Toplevel(bg="Orange")
  t1.title("Modificar Datos")
  t1.geometry('600x400')
  t1.focus_set()
  t1.grab_set()
  t1.transient(master=ventana)

  inf=StringVar()
  t1=Entry(ventana,textvariable=inf)
  t1.grid(row=1,column=1)
  Label(t1,text='Hija',bg="red")
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes dos problemas principalmente:

- Estas reescribiendo el contenido de la variable `t1`. Primero la asignas a a la instancia de `Toplevel` pero después la reutilizas con el `Entry`.
- Los widget que pertenecen a Toplevel deben tener este como padre, no la ventana principal como haces en `t1=Entry(ventana,textvariable=inf)`, esto causa que el widget sea dibujado en la ventana principal como comentas.

Es decir, debería ser algo así:

```
import Tkinter as tk 


ventana = tk.Tk()
ventana.geometry('200x100')

def win2():

    tl = tk.Toplevel(ventana, bg="Orange")
    tl.title("Modificar Datos")
    tl.geometry('600x400')
    tl.focus_set()
    tl.grab_set()
    tl.transient(master=ventana)

    inf = tk.StringVar(tl)
    entry1 = tk.Entry(tl, textvariable=inf)
    entry1.grid(row=0, column=1)
    label1 = tk.Label(tl, text='Hija', bg="red")
    label1.grid(row=0, column=0)


tk.Button(ventana, text="Abrir", command=win2).pack()
ventana.mainloop()
```