# Al instanciar widget, ¿pasar self o master como padre?

Tags: python, tkinter

Me estoy iniciando en Tkinter y en concreto ahora estoy estudiando / revisando el widget `Treeview`.

Estudio y analizo distinto programas de este y otros foros y me ha surgido una duda, y es que unas veces lo instancian con `self` y otras con `master`, entendiendo por `master` padre del widget  contenedor, y yo entiendo que esta es la correcta, pero me extraña que otros, con mucha mas experiencia, empleen la forma `self`. ¿Que se debe usar? ¿El contenedor o el padre?

He hecho la prueba cambiando `self` por `master` y en principio funciona correctamente, pero algo me dice que no es lo mismo. Uno de los dos modos debe ser el correcto

Pongo un ejemplo:

```
class Application(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, main_window):
        super().__init__(main_window)
        main_window.title("Explorador de archivos y carpetas")

        #self.treeview = ttk.Treeview(self) ##### No deberia ser main_Window???? **ORIGINAL**
        self.treeview = ttk.Treeview(main_window)
        self.treeview.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
```

¿Alguien me puede aclarar esta duda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que le debes pasar siempre a todo widget (incluidas `StringVar` y demás variables) es una **referencia al widget padre**, punto. Si no se pasa ninguna referencia el padre será la ventana principal y esto puede dar problemas inesperados:

- [Widgets de ventana hija creada con Toplevel se muestran en la ventana principal](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/130254/15089)
- [¿StringVar y texvariable no funcionan en una ventana secundaria?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/283262/stringvar-y-texvariable-no-funcionan-en-una-ventana-secundaria)

El widget padre es el widget que contiene a nuestro widget a instanciar.

Bien, ahora vamos a ver tu ejemplo. Tiene una clase `Application` que deriva de `Frame` y dentro instancias un `TreeView`. `self` hace referencia a la instancia de esa clase, es decir es un `ttk.Frame`. La pregunta que debes hacerte es:

### ¿Dónde quiero ubicar mi `TreeView`?

- Si usas `main_window` lo ubicas en la ventana principal, es decir, es un widget hermano del frame `Application`.
- Si usas `self` lo ubicas dentro del `Frame` que a su vez está dentro de `main_window`.

La lógica nos dice que `Application` es el widget contenedor base de toda la app y que el `Treeview` y todo widget de la app debería estar dentro del mismo. Lo lógico es usar `self` como padre. De hecho es común usar Frames como base geométrica para estructurar los distintos nieveles de la app.

Ten en cuenta que los administrados de geometría, métodos `grid`, `pack` y `place`, actúan ubicando en el widget padre, no es lo mismo por tanto ubicar fuera o dentro del `Frame`.

Mejor un ejemplo:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Application(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, main_window):
        super().__init__(main_window)
        main_window.title("Explorador de archivos y carpetas")
        s = ttk.Style()
        s.configure('My.TFrame', background='red')
        self["style"] = 'My.TFrame'

        self.btn1 = tk.Button(main_window, text="Botón 1")
        self.btn1.pack()
        self.btn2 = tk.Button(self, text="Botón 2")
        self.btn2.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("600x400")
    root.configure(background='green')
    Application(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

He usado `pack` y dos botones por comodidad, pero esto es irrelevante. Le he asignado un fondo verde a la ventana principal y uno rojo al `Frame` (Application).

- **Si usamos `main_window` como padre del primer botón y `self` para el segundo:**

  ```
   self.btn1 = tk.Button(main_window, text="Botón 1")
   self.btn2 = tk.Button(self, text="Botón 2")
  ```

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- **Si usamos `self` para ambos:**

  ```
  self.btn1 = tk.Button(self, text="Botón 1")
  self.btn2 = tk.Button(self, text="Botón 2")
  ```

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- **Si usamos `main_window` para ambos**:

  ```
  self.btn1 = tk.Button(main_window, text="Botón 1")
  self.btn2 = tk.Button(main_window, text="Botón 2")
  ```

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
  ¿Para que queremos el `Frame`? Para eso no derivamos de `ttk.Frame` y creamos todo en la ventana principal...

Comment: Muy clarificadora tu respuesta y acertados tus ejemplos.   Solo a efectos conceptuales básicos, en mi código ejemplo  <br/>¿super().__init__(main_window) conceptualmente equivalente a self = ttk.Frame(main_window)?

Comment: No, equivale a `ttk.Frame.__init__(self, main_window)`, ambos lo que hacen es llamar al inicializador de la clase padre pero `__init__` no es un constructor, no retorna nada. mejor dicho retorna `None`. La instacia (`self`) la genera el `__new__` de `Application`, esa instancia se pasa al `__init__` de `Application` y desde así se pasa al `__init__` del padre que iniciaiza la instancia con lo necesario para ser un Frame. Si haces `self = ttk.Frame.__init__(self, main_window)` `self ` será `None`. No se si me he medio explicado, es complicado en un comentario por espacio y por el formato.

Comment: Puedes mirate [¿Qué es un cosntructor?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/63451/15089) y [¿Qué es y qué utilidad tiene super en POO?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/130252/15089) a ver si te aclaran algo al respecto.

Comment: No me referia a equivalencia en cuanto a código, sino que en esta sentencia es donde se instancia el frame y se hace que main_window sea el padre. Estudiaré las referencia que me facilitas.

Comment: Eso si, la llamada al inicializador del padre es lo que hace que sea un `ttk.Frame` y se comporte como el. Ya por herencia es un ttk.Frame, pero sin inicializar porque hemos sobrescrito el `__init__` del padre(tiene los métodos heredados de el). La inialización incluye realizar las interacciones necesarias con el intérprete TCL, llamada a otros incializadores o constructores si es necesario, cálculos de geometría, enlace de eventos, ... así como agregar todos los atributos definidos en el `__init__` paterno, lo que incluye hacer que `main_window` sea el padre (`master = <tkinter.Tk object .>`)