# Reemplazando pack() por grid()

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Entendida la lógica a mi pregunta

> [Al instaniar widget, ¿pasar self o master como padre?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/346000/al-instaniar-widget-pasar-self-o-master-como-padre/)

estoy intentando sustituir la funcion pack() por su "equivalente" en grid, y poner a prueba mi aprendizaje.
Para ello he procedido con el primer ejemplo que me proporciona @FJSevilla.
Este es su ejemplo:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Application(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, main_window):
        super().__init__(main_window)
        main_window.title("Explorador de archivos y carpetas")
        s = ttk.Style()
        s.configure('My.TFrame', background='red')
        self["style"] = 'My.TFrame'

        self.btn1 = tk.Button(main_window, text="Botón 1")
        self.btn1.pack()
        self.btn2 = tk.Button(self, text="Botón 2")
        self.btn2.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("600x400")
    root.configure(background='green')
    Application(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Este es mi intento:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# referencias técnicas

# https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/346000/al-instaniar-widget-pasar-self-o-master-como-padre/346007
# https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/posicionar-elementos-en-tkinter/

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Application(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, main_window):
        super().__init__(main_window)
        main_window.title("Explorador de archivos y carpetas")
        s = ttk.Style()
        s.configure('My.TFrame', background='red')
        self["style"] = 'My.TFrame'

        main_window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        main_window.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)


        self.btn1 = tk.Button(main_window, text="Boton 1")
        # self.btn1.pack()
        self.btn1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="n")

        self.btn2 = tk.Button(self, text="Boton 2")
        #self.btn2.pack()
        self.btn2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="n")

        self.grid(sticky="nsew")

        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)      # supongo que en este ejemplo sobra, pero no interfiere


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("600x400")
    root.configure(background='green')
    # Application(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    app = Application(root)
    # app.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
    # app.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Este es el resultado que obtengo:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTLVJ.jpg]
cuando el resultado que deseo es:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEeEf.png]

¿Que es lo que no acabo de entender y estoy omitiendo?

Una pregunta adicional. :-)

En mi código, si en el texto de los botones uso la **o acentuada**, **ó**,
obtengo, al ejecutar el programa el siguiente error:

**SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 3: invalid continuation byte**

Entiendo que la o acentuada no debe tener representación en UTF-8, y he creido entender que Python 3, emplea, por defecto, ese código en el script.

De nuevo,¿Que no acabo de entender y estoy omitiendo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas combinar de forma adecuada `grid.rowconfigure/grid.columnconfigure` para permitir que las filas y columnas puedan expandirse y muy importante, forzar al frame a expandirse todo lo que pueda en las cuatro direcciones con `sticky="nsew"`.

Lo haces casi todo bien, tu error está solo aquí:

```
main_window.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

la fila 0 es la del botón, no la del frame. Al darle mayor peso, la fila 0 se expande reduciendo la 1 (la del frame) a su mínima altura posible. Para que sea la del frame la que se expanda, debes aplicar el peso sobre la fila 1, no la 0:

```
main_window.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
```

El código completo, eliminado lo innecesario podría ser:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Application(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, main_window):
        super().__init__(main_window)
        s = ttk.Style()
        s.configure('My.TFrame', background='red')
        self["style"] = 'My.TFrame'
        self.btn2 = tk.Button(self, text="Botón 2")

        # Permitir a la columna expandirse
        ## permitiendo el centrando del botón. 
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.btn2.grid(row=0, column=0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("600x400")
    root.title("Explorador de archivos y carpetas")
    root.configure(background='green')

    # Permitir a la fila expandirse en altura,
    ## permitiendo al frame hacerlo también. 
    root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)

    # Permitir a la columna expandirse
    ## permitiendo el centrando del botón y el frame. 
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    btn1 = tk.Button(root, text="Botón 1")
    btn1.grid(row=0, column=0)

    app = Application(root)
    app.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")

    root.mainloop()
```

He separado la creación del `Frame` y el botón de la ventana principal de la del contenido del propio `Frame` para encapsular cada widget y que quede más claro. Personalmente prefiero modificar lo imprescindible del widget padre desde un hijo, hace la clase menos portable y el código más confuso. No obstante si quieres hacerlo todo desde la clase es exactamente lo mismo:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Application(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, main_window):
        super().__init__(main_window)
        s = ttk.Style()
        s.configure('My.TFrame', background='red')
        self["style"] = 'My.TFrame'
        main_window.title("Explorador de archivos y carpetas")
        main_window.configure(background='green')
        main_window.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        main_window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        btn1 = tk.Button(main_window, text="Botón 1")
        btn1.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.btn2 = tk.Button(self, text="Botón 2")
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.btn2.grid(row=0, column=0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("600x400")
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

En cuanto al problema con el acento, efectivamente Python 3 usa UTF-8 tanto para el código fuente (por defecto) como para las cadenas (`str`). Pero recuerda guardar el script con codificación UTF-8 (el cómo dependerá de tu IDE/editor), o en su defecto [declarar la adecuada al inicio del script](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/), por ejemplo:

```
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
```

El byte `0xf3` no es un byte válido para UTF-8, pero es la ó en Latin1/ISO 8859-1:

> ```
> >>> "ó".encode("Latin1")
> b'\xf3'
>
> >>> "ó".encode("UTF-8")
> b'\xc3\xb3'
> ```

Comment: @FJSevilla.Visto desde tu enfoque, todo aparece mucho mas claro.

Una pregunta más. He dado peso 1 a la fila 0 de root,
y efectivamente aparece la ventana dividida en dos por la mitad, con el botón1, en el centro de la parte superior verde.
Para que el botón1 me aparezca, centrado y pegado a la parte superior, como está botón2, en parte inferior, le debo de añadir sticky=“n”.
La duda me surge en  ¿Por que boton2, aparece pegado a la parte superior del frame, si en ningún sitio se le indica, al menos explicitamente, sticky=n, a ese botón?. En principio, deberia aparecer también centrado

Comment: Por pasos, el botón o cualquier widget siempre sale centrado en la celda por defecto. Ahora bien, lo que tienes que plantearte no es si el botón se centra, sino el tamaño de su celda. En el caso del botón del frame su fila tiene peso 0, eso quiere decir que no se expande y ocupa la mínima altura  posible. La mínima altura posible es la del botón y esa es la que tiene. Como solo hay una fila se posiciona arriba del todo ocupando lo menos posible, el botón se centra pero en una fila con la misma altura que el....

Comment: En cambio, el botón de `root` está en una fila con peso 1, la fila se expande ocupando toda la altura que tiene disponible. Si agregas `self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)` en el `Frame` observaras que su botón también queda en el centro porque la fila se expande, ya no tiene el alto del botón. No se si me habré medio explicado... :) Por cierto ¿has solucionado lo del acento?

Comment: Lo del acento ha quedado solucionado. Lo que me ha pasado es que en mi comentario original, me pasaba del número de caracteres permitidos y he tenido que eliminar bastante texto, y esa parte ha sido la primera que he eliminado.Ya veo que puedo escribir mas de un comentario para explayarme. :-)

Comment: Parece que el secreto está en entender a fondo el hecho de que el boton tiene la fila sin peso, y el frame que lo contiene si se puede expandir. Algo hay en esa relación que se me escapa, y creo que es el núcleo del entendimiento. Yo pensaba que el posicionamiento se realizaba via sticky, pero en alguna prueba que he hecho, también parece que está escapando algo, porque me ha aparecido que el boton ocupaba todo el frame "nsew", cuando lo que intentaba era que me quedase en el centro.

Comment: si sabes de alguna lectura para torpes que  pueda estudiar y clarificar el tema, te lo agradecería.

Comment: Parece que mi error conceptual estaba en que yo consideraba, en el caso del frame, que la cuadricula única, en nuestro caso, (r=0, c=0)  ocupaba todo el frame, pero según parece y me indicas, su tamaño se limita al mínimo imprescindible para contener el widget, botón en nuestro caso. Su tamaño, (extensión), el de (r=0, c=0), se puede modificar via **weight**.  He estado haciendo pruebas combinando los valores posibles en rowconfigure y columnconfigure y ya me ha quedado claro el posicionamiento. Creo tener las ideas mas claras. Muchas gracias.